# Smartsheet-api, Is there any way to get manually deleted row using smartsheet api or sdk call

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v1

I am deleting row from a sheet, On a sheet I have daily job which needs to recognize the deleted records, I need a way to recognize them using smartsheet api or sdk..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please note I've updated my answer below to add information about webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this scenario (identifying deleted rows) is explicitly supported by the API at this time. Seems like you could still use the API to achieve your goal though, with a bit more work (code) on your part.

Your code would have to get the sheet data (i.e., all sheet rows) at a regular interval and save that data somewhere -- then each time job runs, get the sheet data again and compare that data to the data you saved the previous time the job ran (to identify any rows that had been deleted).

**Edit 9/26: Added Webhooks info**

Note that with the approach I've described above, any rows that had been added AND deleted during the interval between job runs would not be detected. If it's important to identify *each and every time* a row is deleted, a better (and much more efficient) approach would be to use [Webhooks](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#intro-to-webhooks). By using webhooks, your application subscribes to notifications for a specified sheet, and then would receive a callback (HTTP POST) from Smartsheet any time the sheet changes. Your application would need to inspect the information in each callback it receives to identify 'deleted row' events (`eventType` = **deleted** and `objectType` = **row**).

Comment: Can you please provide information of getting deleted row data from the above scenario..

Comment: I've added an answer to the new question you just posted on this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64334700/is-there-any-way-to-get-deleted-row-data-from-smartsheet-using-webhooks/64337033#64337033.  If the answer above and the answer I've posted on your new question is helpful, please mark as accepted and upvote (doing so makes it more likely for others to benefit from the answer in the future). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to add a column with a checkmark named "delete" or something similar, then with automation you can move the row to another sheet when the flag is detected, the row will be removed from the original sheet, but you will have a record of the deleted row in a different sheet that you can read or do what ever you need to do, this will also prevent deletions by mistake and you can even restore the row back if you need to. I don't think you need much code to implement this solution.