# Allow Access to Activity Log with API

Tags: smartsheet-api

We have requirement to find rows deleted using Smart Sheet API. we have tried using c# SDK, but we don't see any option to get Sheet Activity Log. Is this possible using Smartsheet API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the Smartsheet API currently supports accessing the Activity Log data.

FYI - seems like this question is related to another question just posted here by someone else -- [Smartsheet-api, Is there any way to get manually deleted row using smartsheet api or sdk call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059549/smartsheet-api-is-there-any-way-to-get-manually-deleted-row-using-smartsheet-ap). See my feedback there for a potential workaround.