# Is there any way to get deleted row data from smartsheet using webhooks

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2, smartsheet-api-1.1

To notify the events on smartsheet, I have created a webhook. Using I am able to get all events performing on sheet. If I delete a record manually, I am getting the deleted event with rowid, but not the total deleted row data. Is there any way to get the deleted row data?

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The callbacks that you receive via webhooks are simply intended to notify you when events occur -- i.e., by design, each callback contains only enough data to identify the event that triggered the callback.

**Update 10/19/2020:**

Unfortunately, you won't be able to use the [Get Row](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-row) operation to retrieve data for row after it's been deleted. Therefore, seems like you'd need to somehow write/save sheet data elsewhere as the sheet is modified (e.g., perhaps in response to webhook notifications that indicate row data was added/modified?), then you could query this saved sheet data to get row data as rows that are deleted from the actual sheet (i.e., in response to 'row deleted' webhook notifications).

Comment: After deleting the row from smartsheet, Get Row is not able to fetch the row by passing sheetid and rowid, showing row not found..

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Apologies for the oversight in my initial response. I've updated my answer to add additional info.